# What's new in Expert F# 2.0?

Tags: books, f#

I own the first edition of Expert F# by Don, et al. and I'm considering buying the next edition, Expert F# 2.0. But I'm wondering if it's worth it. Sure the syntax will be updated and all, but I'd be more interested if there were new topics covered or just compelling expanded coverage of the same topics otherwise.

Glad to hear from anyone who owns both editions, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is not big, Expert F# 2.0 is a minor revision of Expert F#. If you already know F# and occasionally reference the Expert F# book, then you don't need to buy a new one.

The change from the time Expert F# was written to the present is mainly the library part, and a little bit syntax (e.g. the -> operator in the seq computation expression).

But for a beginner who wants to try the examples in the book, the new version is better as the code examples in the old one may have little incompatibility with the F# 2.0 compiler.